# django user registration error with django_rest_auth package

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

i used django rest auth in my project,but i get these error when i try to create a new user

[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow:) Please provide more details about your bug, problem or anything that you are facing. For example in your case share important parts of your settings.py, more traceback about error you are facing.. So other users could help you with a more details answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django_rest_auth use [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to do some tasks like send an email confirmation after registration. This problem may occur when django try to send this email. You must configure a SMTP backend (check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/email/#email-backends)), otherwise this error will continue.

For development purposes you cant set some variables from django-allauth in your `settings.py` file to disable email verification

```
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True # E-mail address is automatically confirmed by a GET request
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none' # Allow logins with an unverified e-mail address
```

Check all available settings for django-allauth package [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).